# AMPscript loop is showing incorrect output

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

I am trying to create AMPscript to parse through an XML payload and output the correct status in each classification. However, currently, my code is outputting every status in every classification I think I am on the right track, but now I am stuck.

Desired output:

**Held    10**
Pending Release 20
Pending Completion  10
**Pending Fulfillment 20**
Released    30
**Pending Shipment    30**
Ready to Ship   60
Ready for Service   55
Ready to Pack   50
Ready to Pick   40

Current output:

**Held    10**
Pending Release 20
Pending Completion  10
Released    30
Ready to Ship   60
Ready for Service   55
Ready to Pack   50
Ready to Pick   40
**Pending Fulfillment** 20
Pending Release 20
Pending Completion  10
Released    30
Ready to Ship   60
Ready for Service   55
Ready to Pack   50
Ready to Pick   40
**Pending Shipment**    30
Pending Release 20
Pending Completion  10
Released    30
Ready to Ship   60
Ready for Service   55
Ready to Pack   50
Ready to Pick   40

**Code Sample:**

```
%%[

VAR @ShipmentsReleasedRows
SET @ShipmentsReleasedRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@order_xml, "//root/ShipmentClassification", 1)
SET @ShipmentsReleasedRowsCount = RowCount(@ShipmentsReleasedRows)

/* Begin ShipmentsReleasedRowCount Loop */
IF @ShipmentsReleasedRowsCount > 0 THEN
FOR @a = 1 TO @ShipmentsReleasedRowsCount DO

    SET @ShipmentsReleasedRow = Row(@ShipmentsReleasedRows, @a)
    SET @ShipmentsReleasedRow_xml = Field(@ShipmentsReleasedRow ,"XML")
    SET @ShipmentsReleasedRow_xml = Concat('<root>',@ShipmentsReleasedRow_xml,'</root>')


        SET @CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER = BuildRowSetFromXML(@ShipmentsReleasedRow_xml, "//root/CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER", 1)
    IF RowCount(@CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER) > 0 THEN
        SET @CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER = Field(Row(@CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER, 1), "Value")
    ELSE
        SET @CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER = "0"
    ENDIF



        SET @CLASSIF_NAME = BuildRowSetFromXML(@ShipmentsReleasedRow_xml, "//root/CLASSIF_NAME", 1)
    IF RowCount(@CLASSIF_NAME) > 0 THEN
        SET @CLASSIF_NAME = Field(Row(@CLASSIF_NAME, 1), "Value")
    ELSE
        SET @CLASSIF_NAME = "No Name"
    ENDIF


]%%


 <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:auto;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0; width:100%;text-align: center; max-width:520px;">

  <tr align="center">
  <td style="background-color:##F5F5F5;color:#222222;font-family: 'Santral', sans-serif;font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-top: 18px;">
  %%=v(@CLASSIF_NAME)=%%
  </td>
  <td style="background-color:##F5F5F5;color:#222222;font-family: 'Santral', sans-serif;font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-top: 18px;">
  %%=v(@CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER)=%%
  </td>
 </tr>




%%[

/* Begin ShipmentsReleasedStatusRows loop - nested inside the ShipmentsReleasedRowCount Loop */
SET @ShipmentsReleasedStatusRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@order_xml, "//root/ShipmentClassification/ShipmentStatus", 1)
IF RowCount(@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRows) > 0 THEN
    FOR @j = 1 TO RowCount(@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRows) DO

        SET @ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow = Row(@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRows, @j)
        SET @ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow_xml = Field(@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow, "XML")
        SET @ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow_xml = Concat('<root>',@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow_xml,'</root>')


        SET @STATUS_NAME = BuildRowSetFromXML(@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow_xml, "//root/STATUS_NAME", 1)
    IF RowCount(@STATUS_NAME) > 0 THEN
        SET @STATUS_NAME = Field(Row(@STATUS_NAME, 1), "Value")
    ELSE
        SET @STATUS_NAME = "No Name"
    ENDIF


        SET @STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER = BuildRowSetFromXML(@ShipmentsReleasedStatusRow_xml, "//root/STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER", 1)
    IF RowCount(@STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER) > 0 THEN
        SET @STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER = Field(Row(@STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER, 1), "Value")
    ELSE
        SET @STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER = "0"
    ENDIF

  ]%%

 <tr align="center">
  <td style="background-color:##F5F5F5;color:#222222;font-family: 'Santral', sans-serif;font-size:14px; text-align: left; padding-top: 5px;">
  %%=v(@STATUS_NAME)=%%
  </td>
  <td style="background-color:##F5F5F5;color:#222222;font-family: 'Santral', sans-serif;font-size:14px; text-align: right; padding-top: 5px;">
  %%=v(@STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER)=%%
  </td>
 </tr>

 %%[

    NEXT @j
    ENDIF
]%%


 %%[
NEXT @a  /* NEXT ShipmentsReleasedRow */
ENDIF  /* END ShipmentsReleasedRowCount Loop */
ENDIF
]%%

</table>
```

**XML Sample:**

```
    <ShipmentClassification>
        <CLASSIF_CODE>HELD</CLASSIF_CODE>
        <CLASSIF_NAME>Held</CLASSIF_NAME>
        <CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is currently held from fulfillment.</CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>
        <CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>10</CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>
        <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>PENDING_RELEASE</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Pending Release</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is fully defined and is pending release for partner fulfillment.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>20</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>PENDING_COMPLETION</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Pending Completion</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is currently being defined and is held from partner fulfillment.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>10</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
    </ShipmentClassification>
    <ShipmentClassification>
        <CLASSIF_CODE>PENDING_FULFILLMENT</CLASSIF_CODE>
        <CLASSIF_NAME>Pending Fulfillment</CLASSIF_NAME>
        <CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is ready to be fulfilled.</CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>
        <CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>20</CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>
        <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>RELEASED</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Released</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment has been released to the partner for fulfillment.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>30</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
    </ShipmentClassification>
    <ShipmentClassification>
        <CLASSIF_CODE>PENDING_SHIPMENT</CLASSIF_CODE>
        <CLASSIF_NAME>Pending Shipment</CLASSIF_NAME>
        <CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is in the process of being fulfilled.</CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>
        <CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>30</CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>
        <TOTAL_COUNT>2</TOTAL_COUNT>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>READY_TO_SHIP</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Ready to Ship</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is ready to ship.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>60</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>READY_FOR_SERVICE</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Ready for Service</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is now ready for delivery services to be applied.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>55</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>READY_TO_PACK</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Ready to Pack</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is now ready to be packed.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>50</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
        <ShipmentStatus>
            <STATUS_CODE>READY_TO_PICK</STATUS_CODE>
            <STATUS_NAME>Ready to Pick</STATUS_NAME>
            <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is now ready to have the shipment lines picked from within the warehouse.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>
            <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>40</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>
            <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>
        </ShipmentStatus>
    </ShipmentClassification>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you follow the pattern I outlined in [my previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/344767/5202)?  It will produce precisely what you intended -- with just a few minor adjustments:

```ampscript
%%[

var @order_xml, @nodes, @rowCount
set @order_xml = AttributeValue("order_xml")

set @order_xml = ""
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"<root>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"  <ShipmentClassification>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_CODE>HELD</CLASSIF_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_NAME>Held</CLASSIF_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is currently held from fulfillment.</CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>10</CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>PENDING_RELEASE</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Pending Release</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is fully defined and is pending release for partner fulfillment.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>20</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>PENDING_COMPLETION</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Pending Completion</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is currently being defined and is held from partner fulfillment.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>10</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"  </ShipmentClassification>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"  <ShipmentClassification>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_CODE>PENDING_FULFILLMENT</CLASSIF_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_NAME>Pending Fulfillment</CLASSIF_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is ready to be fulfilled.</CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>20</CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>RELEASED</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Released</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment has been released to the partner for fulfillment.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>30</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"  </ShipmentClassification>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"  <ShipmentClassification>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_CODE>PENDING_SHIPMENT</CLASSIF_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_NAME>Pending Shipment</CLASSIF_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is in the process of being fulfilled.</CLASSIF_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>30</CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <TOTAL_COUNT>2</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>READY_TO_SHIP</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Ready to Ship</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is ready to ship.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>60</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>READY_FOR_SERVICE</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Ready for Service</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is now ready for delivery services to be applied.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>55</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>0</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>READY_TO_PACK</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Ready to Pack</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is now ready to be packed.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>50</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    <ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_CODE>READY_TO_PICK</STATUS_CODE>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_NAME>Ready to Pick</STATUS_NAME>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DESCRIPTION>The shipment is now ready to have the shipment lines picked from within the warehouse.</STATUS_DESCRIPTION>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>40</STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"      <TOTAL_COUNT>1</TOTAL_COUNT>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"    </ShipmentStatus>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"  </ShipmentClassification>")
set @order_xml = concat(@order_xml,"</root>")

if indexOf(@order_xml,"<root>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,"//root/ShipmentClassification",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @nodepath
      var @displayOrder
      var @classif_name
      var @url

      set @nodepath = concat("//root/ShipmentClassification[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath,"/CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER"))) > 0 then
          set @displayOrder = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath,"/CLASSIF_DISPLAY_ORDER"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath,"/CLASSIF_NAME"))) > 0 then
          set @classif_name = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath,"/CLASSIF_NAME"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      /* you can end your AMPscript block here and output the HTML directly */
      ]%%

      <br><b>%%=v(@classif_name)=%% %%=v(@displayOrder)=%%</b>

      %%[

      set @nodes2 = BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml, concat("//root/ShipmentClassification[",@i,"]/ShipmentStatus")) 
      set @rowCount2 = rowcount(@nodes2)

      if @rowCount2 > 0 then

        for @j = 1 to @rowCount2 do 

          var @nodepath2
          var @status_name
          var @status_display_order

          set @nodepath2 = concat("//root/ShipmentClassification[",@i,"]/ShipmentStatus[",@j,"]")

          if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath2,"/STATUS_NAME"))) > 0 then
              set @status_name = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath2,"/STATUS_NAME"),0),1),'Value')
          endif

          if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath2,"/STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER"))) > 0 then
              set @status_display_order = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@order_xml,concat(@nodepath2,"/STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER"),0),1),'Value')
          endif

          ]%%

          <br>%%=v(@status_name)=%% %%=v(@status_display_order)=%%

          %%[

        next @j

      endif

    next @i
  
  endif

endif

]%%
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I felt that I failed to explain the full scope of my question. The XML will not be static. I was unsure how to tweak your answer to ensure it would work with a payload that is constantly changing. Thank you so much for helping me with this problem.

Comment: Take out the hard-coded XML string in my example and  `set @order_xml = AttributeValue("order_xml")` should return the XML value from your send context. I only  included the static version so I could test it myself.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!